# time efficient algorithm for picking from a bag

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

You and your friend successfully robbed a jewelry store full of diamond rings. Now, you want to distribute your loot among yourselves but you both got little greedy. You both decided to try your luck while distributing rings. Your bag contains N rings. You both decided to take turns one by one and pick some rings until there is none left in the bag. Since you are the mastermind of the plan, you will take the first turn. The rule goes like this-

1. Take one ring from the bag.
2. Take half of the available rings. This rule can only be applied if the number of rings in the bag is even.

Both robbers will try to maximize the number of rings they have. Find the maximum number of rings you can get at the end of the distribution if both you and the opponent plays optimally.

Input

The first line contains a single integer N(1 ≤ N ≤ 1000000) denotes the number of rings in the bag.

Output

Maximum number of rings you can get.

Sample Input

6

Sample Output
4

Stuck in this question anybody help me, any language works preferably Python.

Comment: What have **YOU** tried / researched so far? Share **YOUR** ideas / findings / code.

Comment: This is not a 'Please Do My Homework for Me'-service.

Comment: I am not good with algorithms but what I did was took two cases for even one where subtract 1 initially and then work from it or divide by 2 and work accordingly and then take the maximum of two cases

Comment: if you know a better  optimal solution then help @MrSmith42

Comment: If you have tried a solution, you should indicate it in the post (code or pseudo-code) and explain why this is not a good one (incorrect result? Too slow?).

Comment: This is not even for a minimax. Basically you have no reason not to take half the rings in the bag every time this is possible, no fancy strategies needed.

Comment: @Shamis that's not true for 12 rings for example. Taking 6 first results in 8 total, whereas taking 1 first results in 9 total.

Comment: @Shamis Not exactly. With n=16 for example, by applyng your greedy strategy, we get 11. By first taking one only, we get 12.

Comment: @Shamis   Look at the cases n=2^k -> difference should increase with k

Comment: Ah, thanks for the correction, my bad. So basically a log(N) improvement is possible with the ideal strategy, over the greedy solution. Still infinitely better, however unless the bag is really big, it won't matter that much ^^.

Comment: @Shamis with 100 rings, greedy wins 55, optimal wins 93. With 98304 rings, greedy wins 49167, optimal wins 98288. Greedy is not in general a good solution to this problem.

Comment: Meditated for a while and finally figured it out. Haste makes waste :-(.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a O(logn) solution. Let call `f(n)` the solution

It is easy to check that:

```
- if (n odd) f(n) = n - f(n-1)
- if (n even) f(n) = max(n - f(n-1), n - f(n/2))
```

Explanation: in `n` is odd the only possibility is to pick one ring, and if `n` is even, we have the choice, pick one ring or half of the packet.

These relations allow a simple iterative solution, O(n) complexity.

However, a recursive solution with a complexity O(logn) is obtained by noting the following:

- if `n == 4k+2` -> better to take half of the rings. In next step, the other can only take one ring
- if `n == 4k (and n > 4)` -> better to take one ring only. Then, the other can only take one and then, we arrive in the previous favorable case

Here is a simple code to illustrate this algorithm.

It compares the results of the O(n) iterative solution and the O(logn) recursive solution.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

//  Iterative O(n) solution
int rings_iterative (int n) {
    std::vector<int> f (n+1);
    f[0] = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        if (i%2) {
            f[i] = i - f[i-1];
        } else {
            f[i] = std::max(i - f[i/2], i - f[i-1]);
        }
    }
    return f[n];
}

//  Recursive O(logn) solution
int rings_recursive (int n) {
    //std::cout << "n = " << n << std::endl;
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n%2) return n - rings_recursive (n-1);
    if (((n/2) % 2) || (n <= 4)) {      // n = 4k+2 -> divide by 2
        return n - rings_recursive(n/2);
    } else {                // n = 4k -> take one ring only
        return 1 + rings_recursive(n-2);
    }
    return -1;
}

int main () {
    int n = 999876;
    int ring1, ring2;
    ring1 = rings_iterative (n);
    ring2 = rings_recursive (n);
    
    std::cout << "n = " << n << " -> " << ring1 << " and " << ring2 << std::endl;
        
    int n_min = 643831;
    int n_max = 653875; 
    for (n = n_min; n <= n_max; ++n) {
        ring1 = rings_iterative (n);
        ring2 = rings_recursive (n);
        if (ring1 != ring2) {
            std::cout << "n = " << n << " -> " << ring1 << " and " << ring2 << std::endl;
            return 1;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "No difference\n";
    return 0;
}
```